# Removing CDATA tags from soap response

Tags: c#, xml, asmx

I'm creating a webservice (c# *.asmx) that is supposed to be a drop in replacement for an existing service, the original XML is a bit terrible so I'm creating my own xml and just returning a string (xml as a string), but I'm getting this:

```
<GetAllResponse xmlns="http://oursiteURL.org.uk/webserviceURL/">
    <GetAllResult>
      <![CDATA[<fs><ts><more-xml-intepreted-as-a-string-in-here>
```

but that CDATA section is not in the original

my webservice's WebMethod signature is as follows:

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetAll(string code) {}
```

Is it possible to remove that CDATA tag and just have the innertext in the response?

To clarify, I'm creating the service, the service needs to return precisely what the old service does, and the old service returns a xml soap envelope with xml inside, but what my method above does is return a soap envelope with a text 'payload', but really the 'payload' is xml and I don't want it returning in a CDATA tag at all because that breaks the xml I'm trying to create

Comment: You mean like `<GetAllResponse xmlns="http://oursiteURL.org.uk/webserviceURL/"><GetAllResult>&lt;fs&gt;&lt;ts`? Why does it matter? CDATA is just one of a couple semanticaly equivalent ways of serializing text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return pure XML from asmx web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784818/how-do-i-return-pure-xml-from-asmx-web-service)

Comment: @TomBlodget no it must not include a CDATA tag at all, xml inside of a CDATA tag is not xml, people already integrated with this service will not suddenly expect text instead of xml structure

Comment: :@HereticMonkey that 'duplicate' specifically says they dont want to return a soap response. Im already returning xml, I NEED TO RESPOND IN A SOAP ENVELOPE